Creating a serial ID sequence that is unique across all tables in an SQL database AND doesn't require redundant entry creation/edits?
I'm building a database for recording extremely detailed information about individual items in a collection that spans a number of different media types (books, CDs, DVDs, etc). Every item in the collection is unique (no duplicates/multiple copies) and will have a unique table entry. These entries will be contained by different tables, according to media type. I want each item to have a unique ID code (serial). I'm figuring out how to ensure that EVERY entry has a unique code, regardless of format (so id = unique across all tables). No two items, regardless of media type, should have the same id code.
A UNIQUE constraint would only apply within a single table, not across all tables in the database.
A master list with very limited data associated could generate the unique id, which would then have all media-type tables as child tables (possibly by using a foreign key association):
CREATE TABLE entrymasterlist (
masterid SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
entrytitle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
primarycontributer VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
mediatype VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

However, using a master table with media-type tables as children would require the user to first create a master reference and THEN create the detailed item entry in the relevant child table. This could work, if it was possible for an entry in the master table to automatically create a matching entry in the correct media-type table (mediatype = book creates an entry in the books table) with the id and title fields being autopopulated from the master table, but it would still be clunky to have to edit the generated entry to fill out the more specific data fields of the child table (redundancy for the user).
Answers to the closest matches in Stack Overflow questions on unique ID fields have the same issue of being reliant on the parent table entry, which creates the redundancy issue described above. For example: Unique serial ID over all subtypes.
What is a different way to achieve the desired result of item ids that are fully unique across media-type tables without the input redundancy?
Or do I need to use a master table and just find a way to work around it or minimize it (if it is not possible to entirely get rid of the input redundancy)?

What is your 1 question? PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.

The simplest way would be for 1) Use Create Sequence to make sequence. 2) Have the media tables PK field use the sequence as their default value. Caveat sequences are not guaranteed to be gapless. Read the Notes section of the sequence link for more information.

If you're going to split a serial across multiple tables then the actual sequence value loses its meaning and there's not much point using a serial, so you may as well use something with inherent uniqueness, like a UUID4.

I don’t understand the requirement and don’t see why you would want to, but you could use a UUID. No need for a sequence and next to impossible to create the same uuid twice. Even across multiple servers

"master-child" tables is the correct approach to Polymorphic Associations in a database. See eg https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/323278/220697 The user shouldn't be editing the database directly anyway, you just need to write a procedure AddBook AddCd etc that can insert multiple tables.

"I want" is not the same as "I need." Is there a business case for unique IDs across tables or is it just personal whim? Even if there is a business case, is it worth additional complexity? There are many approaches to address cross table unique IDs. One approach would be to have a foreign key constraint on the media tables that references a master ID table and use triggers on the media tables to populate the master ID table. Handling the ID synchronization with triggers in this manner eliminates the need for the application program to even be aware of the master ID table.

Unique id across all tables. Well do not use sequence to generate pk, instead use uuid. For v12 and prior see uuid-ossp Functions.

The input redundancy doesn't exist: it is the job of your application to create two INSERTs whenever the user adds an item. If you plan to not use a program to handle this, but want to let your end users type SQL statements into an interactive database client, you have already lost: SQL is both too complicated and too powerful (and hence dangerous) for end users.
The master table with the foreign key is the way to go if you want to absolutely guarantee uniqueness. But you can go a simpler way: if you use the same sequence for all tables, you will automatically get what you want. There will be no constraint to enforce uniqueness, but if you don't override the default value, you will get it.
CREATE SEQUENCE myschema.seq;

CREATE TABLE myschema.item1 (
   id bigint DEFAULT nextval('myschema.seq') PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE myschema.item2 (
   id bigint DEFAULT nextval('myschema.seq') PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
);

...

